# F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_factory.cc:77] Duplicate registration of device factory for type GPU with the same priority 210

Tags: c++, tensorflow

When excute my binary c++ file, this error happened.
I compile my c++ file with tensorflow_cc.so by using make all, and the version of tensorflow is 1.8.
Does anyone have met this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We recently encountered this error. It happened when we inadvertently linked against both libtensorflow.so (`-ltensorflow`) and libtensorflow_cc.so (`-ltensorflow_cc`). It went away when we picked one.